# Custom Radio Button Not Showing Android

Tags: android, xml, radio-button

I want to set a custom radio button. I have created a separate selector XML file as below:

/drawable/radio_btn_background

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radio_active"
    android:state_checked="true"
     />
<item
    android:state_checked="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radio_normal" />
```

Radio Button:

```
   <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/radio_btn_background"
    android:text="@string/english"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/shadow_view" />
```

**When I click the radio button it is not working properly. And once the radio button is checked, it is not toggling on click. It is in the checked state forever.**

@drawable/ic_radio_active is an SVG file [Also tried with png file, but same result]

Output I want
[image]

Output I am getting is only the blue background color without a tick mark [colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark of app is also that color].

Comment: Have you added the RadioButtons within the `RadioGroup`? Note that a radio button cannot be unchecked by the user once checked, unlike `CheckBox`

Comment: yeah..thank you it fixed the checked problem..but what about the selector?

Comment: try using `android:drawableStart` instead of `android:button`